# Cannot drop index on partition table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `Customer` with three columns and table was partitioned by `score` into 10 partitions, from `customer_0` to `customer_9`

```
         Customer table
      id  |  name  | score
       1  | Light  |  90
       2  | Missa  |  10
```

There are indexes created on each partition and global index on column `score`

```
 customer_0
 cust_score_0_idx"  "CREATE INDEX cust_score_0_idx ON customer_0 USING btree (score)
 customer
 cust_score_idx"    "CREATE INDEX cust_score_idx ON customer_0 USING btree (score)
```

As you can see in the above the `partition-0` has index and table as well has same index with different name, now when i'm trying to delete the one on `partition-0` i'm facing issue with a unknown constraint

```
ERROR:  cannot drop index cust_score_0_idx because index cust_score_idx requires it
HINT:  You can drop index cust_score_idx instead.
SQL state: 2BP01
```

So these tables are created long back and i don't know what sql/constraint they used, but now i'm trying to figure out what is stopping dropping the partition index independently.

But as to note, once i drop index on table, it automatically drops the index on partitions, and after that i'm able to create and drop index independently on table and partition.

so i'm more curious how to setup partition index as dependent on global index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found from the [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) documentation, for the partitioned tables, indices have to be created individually on each partition and then finally need to be attached to index created on table. That is the specific limitation from postgres and if partition indices are not attached then table index remains invalid

> As explained above, it is possible to create indexes on partitioned tables so that they are applied automatically to the entire hierarchy. This is very convenient, as not only will the existing partitions become indexed, but also any partitions that are created in the future will. **One limitation is that it's not possible to use the CONCURRENTLY qualifier when creating such a partitioned index. To avoid long lock times, it is possible to use CREATE INDEX ON ONLY the partitioned table; such an index is marked invalid, and the partitions do not get the index applied automatically. The indexes on partitions can be created individually using CONCURRENTLY, and then attached to the index on the parent using ALTER INDEX .. ATTACH PARTITION. Once indexes for all partitions are attached to the parent index, the parent index is marked valid automatically.**

**Example :**

```
 CREATE INDEX measurement_usls_idx ON ONLY measurement (unitsales);

 CREATE INDEX measurement_usls_200602_idx
       ON measurement_y2006m02 (unitsales);
 ALTER INDEX measurement_usls_idx
       ATTACH PARTITION measurement_usls_200602_idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

An index on a partitioned table is a partitioned index, that is, it consists of an index on every partition. You cannot drop `cust_score_0_idx` because it is a part of `cust_score_idx`, and without it `cust_score_idx` would be incomplete.

To get rid of `cust_score_0_idx`, you have to drop the index on the partitioned table (`cust_score_idx`); then all its partitions are dropped automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but `cust_score_0_idx` and `cust_score_idx` are created independently right ? and creating index on table doesn't create index on partitions automatically correct ?

Comment: No, both are wrong. Creating an index on the partitioned table will automatically create the indexes on the partitions. If there is already a matching index on the prospective partition, it will be "repurposed" as a partition of the partitioned index.